# very simple AngularJS data binding not working

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I am completely new to AngularJS.

I have this very simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   Name:  <input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/> {{ name }}


    <script src="angular.min.js>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it only shows `{{name}}` and not the actual input.

The `angular.min.js` is in the right folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistakenly added `> symbol` in end of file name.

Change

```
<script src="angular.min.js>"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/vbh4sl6YUOEiLquaFPLh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem on Eclipse Kepler. I found that angular.min.js version matters. In my case, script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/**1.2.5**/angular.min.js"> works, but script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/**1.4.8**/angular.min.js"> doesn't work.

I haven't had a chance to see why yet.

BTW, I downloaded AngularJS plugin to Eclipse is from http://oss.opensagres.fr/angularjs-eclipse/1.2.0/

Comment: commented to make sure script tag removed to show my whole post: